# awk function comparator to find datapoints inbetween two values

Tags: linux, awk

I have attempted to use the awk operator in order to find certain values within a vcf file. Supposedly, this should give me values in between 31497996 and 31510225 in column 2. But this just generates numbers outside of that region?

I have also attempted to use +$2 in front to convert the values from a string to numbers, but that also wasn't successful.

```
awk '$1=="chr6" && $2<"31510225" && $2>"31497996" {print $0}' test.vcf > test.txt
```

output

```
chr6    3150515 rs3799216
chr6    3150783 rs3799218
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post sample of input  also in your question to make your question clear, thank you.

Comment: Please add sample of the contents of `test.vcf`

Comment: 7-digit data vs. 8-digit script limits?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this script just compares two strings, no numbers. If you're going to compare numbers, just remove those quotation marks around `"31510225"` and `"31497996"`.

```sh
awk '$1=="chr6" && $2<31510225 && $2>31497996 {print $0}' test.vcf > test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "\t" '$1 == "chr6" && $2 < 31510225 && $2 > 31497996' file.vcf
```

But this will be slow compared to querying an indexed VCF/BCF file using [tabix](http://www.htslib.org/doc/tabix.html) or [bcftools](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bcftools.html). These tools make it easy and super fast to query other positions without again having to iterate through your (often) large list of variants. Consider instead:

Firstly, `bgzip` (htslib) your VCF file:

```
bgzip file.vcf
```

Secondly, index your bgzipped VCF file with either tabix or bcftools:

```
# with tabix
tabix file.vcf.gz

# with bcftools
bcftools index file.vcf.gz
```

Finally, retrieve the region of interest by supplying a region string:

```
# with tabix
tabix file.vcf.gz chr6:31510225-31497996

# with bcftools
bcftools view file.vcf.gz chr6:31510225-31497996
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to all, I just manually scrolled through the file and found that there were no data in between the region.